# JQVMAP with requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, jvectormap

How do I use [jquery vector maps](http://jqvmap.com/) with require.js as a module?

Is JVP amd compatible? It'll be great if someone could link to an example or suggest some workaround.

I can't use shim option as I'm using old require.js and can't update it.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the library with a `define` yourself, effectively achieving what the `shim` option does. A quick test setup:

**jqvmap-wrapped.js**

```
// to simplify the example used jQuery named as "jquery.js" 
define(['jquery'], function(jQuery){
   // original jqvmap.js goes here
   // (...)

   // please note: not returning anything
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-main="index" src="require.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="vmap" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
define(['jquery', 'jqvmap-wrapped'], function ($, _jqvmapEmpty) {
   console.log('jQuery=', $);
   console.log('jqvmap-wrapped=', _jqvmapEmpty);
   console.log('jqvmap attached to jQuery? ', $.prototype.vectorMap);

   $('#vmap').vectorMap({
     // params
   });
})
```

A word of explanation: the plugin adds itself to jQuery, it has no "standalone" version. The wrapper module doesn't return anything, it just has a side-effect of adding `jqvmap` to the `jQuery` object; that's why the `_jqvmapEmpty` variable itself is `undefined`. It's available through jQuery, though, so you can use it in the same manner you'd do it in a non-modular code.